# How can I convert and display this NSDate more efficiently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:self.todayRecord.datetime];
```

self.todayRecord.datetime is a string that looks something like:

```
2016-02-15 12:33:00
```

I want to display the same date but without the seconds like this:

```
2016-02-15 12:33
```

The way I can think of right now is make another date formatter and just format out the seconds. Something like this:

```
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:self.todayRecord.datetime];
```

I did this and display became (null).

Comment: just remove `SS` from `df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";`

Comment: What have you read about date formatting?

Comment: oops, i made a typo. that's what I tried but output became (null)

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency, don't store dates as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
//create the NSDateFormatter first
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
// set the date format based on your String
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
// convert the string to date
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:self.todayRecord.datetime];
// set the final dateformat what the output do you need
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
// in here you get final output on String
NSString *finalString = [df StringFromdate:date];
// in here you get final output on date 
NSDate *FinalDate = [df dateFromString:finalString];
```